# LTspice XVII: Subcircuit pin names in Operating Point analysis

Tags: ltspice

Is there a way to have subcircuit names show up in the Operating Point analysis?

For instance, I have this test circuit:

[image: Schematic]

Here, the pins are named A and K for the opto's LED and C and E for its transistor pins.  In Transient analysis, measuring the currents is intuitive:  the traces are named Ix(U1:A) for anode current, Ix(U1:C) for collector current, etc.  But when I run an Operating Point analysis, the pins are simply numbered:

[image: OP]

**EDIT:** Below is the subcircuit model.

```
.subckt TLP383 1 2 3 4
R1 N003 2 2
D1 1 N003 LD
G1 3 N002 N003 2 {gain}
C1 1 2 30p
Q1 3 N002 4 [4] NP
.model LD D(Is=1.2e-12 N=1.6 Cjo=30p)
.model NP NPN(Bf=610 Vaf=140 Ikf=15m Rc=1 Cjc=19p Cje=7p Cjs=7p C2=1e-15)
.ends TLP383
```

The `{gain}` value for -GR and -GB is `3.25m` and `6.78m`, respectively.

Comment: I was going to suggest renaming the net but it looks you've done that already with `out_gb`, `out_gr`, etc.?

Comment: @KingDuken Indeed I have.  Nice that the voltage at those nodes are spat out, but unfortunately the currents into/out of the ICs are neglected.

Comment: I'm afraid cosmetics such as this are not a thing Mike (the creator) is very fond of. You *could* try to write a request for this, but I honestly doubt the success of it. If you do decide to do it, though, make sure you are short and to the point.

Comment: What does your subcircuit look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to have subcircuit names show up in the Operating Point
>   analysis?

No and there probably wont be, subcircuits are like functions. The nets are local just like variables have scope inside of a function.

You wouldn't all nodes to show up in that list, if you had a circuit with several IC's, the list could be hundreds of items long and then there would be questions of how to reduce the size of the list.

If you really do have to have a node on the inside, you'll need to edit the component and bring it out of the part. Or you could copy out the subcircuit and build it in your schematic.